# Unexpected results in Linq query always + 1

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below code and I'm expecting a different result.
I have excepted that following result: **100 ,110 ,120 , 200, 500**

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  namespace ConsoleApplication11
  {
    public class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var values = new List<int> { 100, 110, 120, 200 , 500 };

        //  In my mind the result shall be like (100,0) => 100 + 0 = 100 
        //  In my mind the result shall be like (110,0) => 110 + 0 = 110 etc. 
        var sumLinqFunction = new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) => x + y);
        var outputs = values.Select(sumLinqFunction);

        foreach (var o in outputs)
          Console.WriteLine(o);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Console output (real result)**

```
100
111
122
203
504
```

I'm  wondering now about this +1 from where came?

Comment: Why do you expect `y` to be `0`?

Comment: I was going to suggest [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx), but I have no clue what actual functionality was expected here.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve with your code?

Comment: @PavelMurygin I need to call the select with the default value 0 and not the index!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is because the second parameter of the [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method overload you are using is just the index of the item in the input set.

EDIT:

As @user7116 suggested, you may want to simply include in your projection function a value from the outer scope:

```
int y = 0;
var results = values.Select(x => x + y);
```

Comment: Ohh really? why the select does not just use the default value 0 if the parameter is not defined!!!!!

Comment: Can I just use 0 if the paramerter is not defined force the select or something like that

Comment: @BassamAlugili: that makes no sense w.r.t. the C# language and the .Net Framework.

Comment: user7116 for me the LINQ is very stupid and this MAGIC OVERlOAD make no sense

Comment: @BassamAlugili: So basically you want to add 0 to all values in the list. Why don't you just leave it as it is? Btw, the "MAGIC OVERLOAD" is very useful. As useful as a `for-loop` is.

Comment: @BassamAlugili nothing "magic" in that overload, it just passes the item index to the projection function.

Comment: @BassamAlugili: unexpected default values are *magic*, overloads are just that...overloads.

Answer (score 7):

Your `Func`, `sumLinqFunction`, is expecting two parameters, adding them up and then returning their result.

When you are using that in Select statement it is like:

```
var outputs = values.Select((x, y) => x + y);
```

which uses the overload of [**Select**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which expects the second parameter to be index.

> The first argument to selector represents the element to process.
>   **The second argument to selector represents the zero-based index of that element in the source sequence.** This can be useful if the
>   elements are in a known order and you want to do something with an
>   element at a particular index, for example. It can also be useful if
>   you want to retrieve the index of one or more elements.

So `y` starts with `0`. With each iteration the index (`y`) moves to next element, thus you 
see the increment of `+1`.

To explain it a bit more, you can modify your `Func` to display current values of `x` and `y` like:

```
var sumLinqFunction = new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("x: {0} , y: {1}", x, y);
        return x + y;
    });
var outputs = values.Select(sumLinqFunction).ToList(); //iterate to get the results.
```

This would give you:

```
x: 100 , y: 0
x: 110 , y: 1
x: 120 , y: 2
x: 200 , y: 3
x: 500 , y: 4
```

For your comment:

> I need to call the select with the default value 0 and not the index!

Then instead of having a `Func` you can simply do:

```
int y = 0;
var outputs = values.Select(r => r + y);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) overload.

It just adds the index to the current value:

```
100 + 0
110 + 1
120 + 2
200 + 3
500 + 4
```

You don't need a query for the expected output.

```
var values = new List<int> { 100, 110, 120, 200 , 500 };

foreach (var o in outputs)
      Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Comment: More than likely the OP will want to add some arbitrary value at some point; akin to `int y = 0; var results = values.Select(x => x + y);`

Answer (score 4):

Check the definition of the Select overload you are invoking:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx

In this case you are invoking this overload:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector
)
```

whereby selector is (emphasis mine)

> A transform function to apply to each source element; **the second
>   parameter of the function represents the index of the source
>   element**.

So your selector lambda is returning the number at the current array index PLUS the array index, hence

**(x, y) => x + y**

(100,0) =>100+0

(110,1) =>110+1

(120,2) =>120+2

(200,3) =>200+3

(500,4) =>500+4

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use some function with 'default' parameter value:

```
    var values = new List<int> { 100, 110, 120, 200 , 500 };

    var sumLinqFunction = new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) => x + y);
    var outputs = values.Select(i => sumLinqFunction(i, 0));
```